# Sending JMS Messages From WildFly Swarm To WebLogic 11g

Tags: jms, weblogic11g, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to replicate in Wildfly Swarm the process of sending JMS messages from Wildfly 8 to Weblogic  without using Camel (http://blog.eisele.net/2015/07/sending-jms-messages-from-wildfly-8-to-weblogic-with-camel.html) but without success.

The things that I have did tillnow are the following:

1) Module creation for wlthint3client.jar (src/main&resources/modules/custom/oracle/weblogic):

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:2.0" name="custom.oracle.weblogic">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="wlthint3client.jar">
            <filter>
                <exclude-set>
                    <path name="javax.ejb"/>
                    <path name="javax.ejb.spi"/>
                    <path name="javax.transaction"/>
                    <path name="javax.jms"/>
                    <path name="javax.xml"/>
                    <path name="javax.xml.stream"/>
                </exclude-set>
            </filter>
        </resource-root>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="sun.jdk" export="false" services="import">
            <exports>
                <include-set>
                    <path name="sun/security/acl"/>
                    <path name="META-INF/services"/>
                </include-set>
            </exports>
        </module>
        <module name="com.sun.xml.bind" />
        <module name="org.omg.api"/>
        <module name="javax.ejb.api" export="false"   />
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"  export="false" />
        <module name="javax.jms.api"  export="false" />
        <module name="javax.xml.stream.api" export="false"  />
        <module name="org.picketbox" optional="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.web" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.ejb3" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.hornetq" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Now, the problem is how translate the jms-bridge configuration into the project-stages.yml:

```
<jms-bridge name="wls-bridge" module="custom.oracle.weblogic">
                <source>
                    <connection-factory name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    <destination name="java:/jms/sourceQ"/>
                </source>
                <target>
                    <connection-factory name="jms/WFMessagesCF"/>
                    <destination name="jms/WFMessages"/>
                    <context>
                        <property key="java.naming.factory.initial"
                              value="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"/>
                        <property key="java.naming.provider.url" 
                              value="t3://127.0.0.1:7001"/>
                    </context>
                </target>
                <quality-of-service>AT_MOST_ONCE</quality-of-service>
                <failure-retry-interval>2000</failure-retry-interval>
                <max-retries>10</max-retries>
                <max-batch-size>500</max-batch-size>
                <max-batch-time>500</max-batch-time>
                <add-messageID-in-header>true</add-messageID-in-header>
            </jms-bridge>
```

Till now I was unabled to replicate it in the project-stages-yml file and see some information logged when I start my java project. 
Someone would be kind to helpp me with this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a section in `project-defaults.yml` that uses the keys mentioned [here](http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2018.1.0/#_messaging).

For example, the above would start like:

```
swarm:
  messaging-activemq:
    jms-bridges:
      wls-bridge:
        failure-retry-interval: 2000
        max-batch-size: 500
        max-batch-time: 500
        source-connection-factory: java:/ConnectionFactory
        source-destination: java:/jms/sourceQ
        target-connection-factory: jms/WFMessagesCF
```

That's not the full list of settings, but should be enough to get you started in converting it to yaml.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ken. It could be work, but in what part of my project-stages-yml I need to specifiy a reference to the wlthint3client module? I guess that this point is the most important key to start up the resource adapter when I start my project. Any idea?

Comment: Hi Kent Trying to do the configuration above and adding the rest of te information I get this error at runtime:ERROR <org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation> <Controller Boot Thread> WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "messaging-activemq"),("jms-bridge" => "wls-bridge")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.richiesteDownloadQCF"]

Comment: I don't see anything referred to as `richiesteDownloadQCF` in the above code snippets, so not sure why it's trying to reference something with that name from JNDI

Comment: Hi Ken. You're right. It wasa mistake. The real target connection factory name is richiesteDownloadQCF, not jms/WFMessagesCF. So... I don't know the reason wht I'm getting the error indicated first. Do you have any idea, please? Thanks a lot again

Comment: Hi, Ken. I finished to add the rest of the jms-bridge xml format into yml format, but starting the java project nothing happens. I send a message but is not received by the Weblogic JMS queue.

Comment: I'm getting this error now: 2018-02-09 13:56:03 WARN <org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.bridge> <Thread-61> AMQ342010: Failed to connect JMS Bridge: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [t3://sapvxs015:7676 (No connection provider for URI scheme "t3" is installed)]

Comment: I've not seen a URI that starts with `t3` before. Is that right? The message is because it doesn't know what to do with `t3` urls, as opposed to http

Comment: The URI that starts with t3 is defined inside the target-context section in the project-stages.yml: target-context: java.naming.factory.initial: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory java.naming.provider.url: "t3://sapvxs015:7676"

Comment: Sorry, I mean what url protocol is it? The error message is saying it doesn't know what t3 means. If it was http or https it would know what to do with it

Comment: T3 is the protocol used to transport information between WebLogic servers and other types of Java programs. WebLogic keeps track of every Java virtual machine connected to the application. To carry traffic to the Java virtual machine, WebLogic creates a single T3 connection. This type of connection maximizes efficiency by eliminating multiple protocols used to communicate between networks, thereby using fewer operating system resources.

Comment: Right. What I'm saying though is that there appears to be some JAR that needs to be present for Java to know how to handle the t3 protocol type.